# How to extract number from end of the string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a string like `"Titile Something/17"`. I need to cut out `"/NNN"` part which can be `3, 2, 1` digit number or may not be present.

How you do this in python? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have already tried

Comment: The deal is you show us what you've tried and code and how you'd approach the problem, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: @EdChum never thought about asking people write code for me, but a code sample - feedback is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d{0,3}` matches from zero upto three digits. `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

```
re.search(r'/\d{0,3}$', st).group()
```

Example:

```
>>> re.search(r'/\d{0,3}$', 'Titile Something/17').group()
'/17'
>>> re.search(r'/\d{0,3}$', 'Titile Something/1').group()
'/1'
```

Comment: Nice, but not so readable :) **thefourtheye**'s sample better, how do you think?

Comment: @DmitrijA fourtheye's sample would work on `"Titile Something/foo"` input also. But i think you want the last part which has zero or upto three digits.

Comment: Yes you are correct here. But if there is no number, there is no slash also. For this i have to check result is not `None` before calling `.group()` on it.

Comment: i think you could easily check whether `re.search` returns a match object or not.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need RegEx here, simply use the built-in [`str.rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) function and [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1903116), like this

```
>>> data = "Titile Something/17"
>>> data[:data.rindex("/")]
'Titile Something'
>>> data[data.rindex("/") + 1:]
'17'
```

Or you can use [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition), like this

```
>>> data.rpartition('/')[0]
'Titile Something'
>>> data.rpartition('/')[2]
'17'
>>>
```

**Note:** This will get any string after the last `/`. Use it with caution.

If you want to make sure that the split string is actually full of numbers, you can use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function, like this

```
>>> data[data.rindex("/") + 1:].isdigit()
True
>>> data.rpartition('/')[2].isdigit()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = "Titile Something/17"

print data.split("/")[0]
'Titile Something' 
print data.split("/")[-1] #last part string after separator /
'17'
```

or

```
print data.split("/")[1] # next part after separator in this case this is the same
'17'
```

when You want add this to the list use strip() to remove newline "\n"

```
print data.split("/")[-1].strip()
'17'
```

~

Comment: Thanks for input and welcome. But  `split()` returns an array of items split by /, this not 100% matches my task.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to cut out "/NNN"

```
x = "Titile Something/17"
print re.sub(r"/.*$","",x)   #cuts the part after /
print re.sub(r"^.*?/","",x)  #cuts the part before /
```

Using `re.sub` you can what you want.